# Converting Value from database to Bensampo enum key in string

Tags: php, laravel, enums

Hi guys im using [BenSampo enum](https://github.com/BenSampo/laravel-enum) in laravel and i want to send an email with the enum key, but the database is returning an int value. how do i convert that int to the enum Key?

see an example of my code below

enum

```
final class Courier extends Enum
{
    const USPS = 0;
    const UPS = 1;
    const Fedex = 2;
}
```

controler

```
$newShipment =  Shipment:: create([
            'user_id' => $request->mailBoxNo,
            'vendor'=> $request->vendor,
            'weight'=> $request->weight,
            'transitStatus'=> '1',
            'isInvoiceReady'=>'0',
            'trackingNumber'=> $trackingNumber, 
            'CourierTrackingNumber'=> $request->CourierTrackingNumber, 
            'CourierName'=> $request->Courier, 

        ]);          
       
        $owner = User::find($request->mailBoxNo);   
       
        Mail:: to($owner->email)->send(new RecievedShipment($owner  , $newShipment) );
```

Email Page to Blade to send the courier name.

```
  @component('mail::message')
    # Hi {{$PackageOwner->name}}
    
    A package was recieved at our warehouse for you from {{$package->CourierName}}, with tracking number {{$package->CourierTrackingNumber}}.Your Shipping Yaad the tracking number is {{$package->trackingNumber}}
    
    @component('mail::button', ['url' => ''])
    View Package Details
    @endcomponent
    
    Thanks,<br>
    Shipping Yaad
    @endcomponent
```

Model

```
class Shipment extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'vendor',
        'weight',
        'transitStatus',
        'isInvoiceReady',
        'trackingNumber',
        'CourierName',
        'CourierTrackingNumber',
            
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'courierNameEnum' => Courier::class, // Example enum cast
    ];


}
```

The {{$package->CourierName}} is returning the enum number from the database, but I want it to return the enum key/Name, for example if the value is 0, I want it to return USPS.

How can I do that?

Comment: Define a map of your Couriers, like `[0 => 'USPS', 1 => 'UPS', 2 => 'FedEx']`, then if you did `$courierMap[$package->CourierName]` it would return the name. If you defined that as a `const` on the `Courier` class, then `Courier::names[$package->CourierName]`, etc. Defining them as `USPS = 0`, `UPS = 1`, etc can work for assignment, but not well when checking (unless you did `if ($package->CourierName == Courier::USPS) { return 'USPS'; } elseif (...)`, but that isn't the best approach. Try to implement something like that 

Comment: Im confused, why do i need to define a map, isnt that the purpose of the enum?

Comment: Oh, you're using some kind of package for this? I see now you mention it in the title, but you didn't include a link to it or describe how its supposed to work. If the package takes care of that kind of mapping, then no, you don't need a manual map; I was commenting under the impression you were simply using an enum of `0, 1, 2` in you database. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Thanks for understanding. I just want to know how to convert the value I'm getting from the db to the key for the enum. Im not seeing anything online  how to do so

Comment: This maybe? https://github.com/BenSampo/laravel-enum#attribute-casting You'd set `Shipment`'s `CourierName` attribute to an instance of `Courier::class`. Can you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69828614/edit) to include your `Shipment` model definition?

Comment: i updated the  question with the model